# The Class 'SleepingOwl\Admin\AdminServiceProvider' not found?

Tags: laravel

I have included the Service Providers, and added the aliases in the app.php
I try enter in my URL http://canabis.local/admin it give me that 'Class 'SleepingOwl\Admin\AdminServiceProvider' not found?'

What is the problem? in my laravel 5

Comment: Guessing you're using https://github.com/sleeping-owl/admin ? Did you follow all the installation steps?

Comment: ^ By the sounds of it you only completed the first three steps and still need to run the fourth where you `publish` and `install`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following commands:

1. composer self-update
2. composer update
3. php artisan vendor:publish
4. php artisan admin:install

Answer (score -1):

What type of ServiceProvider are you using? How are you using it in a code?

This usually happens when you try to use a class from a different package - I assume your app is named "SleepingOwl" and you are now in namespace SleepingOwl\Admin. Just include this line on the top of the file:

```
use InsertExtensionNameHere\AdminServiceProvider;
```

Otherwise provide more code, as this is quite vague question.

Comment: I don't think the poster is trying to create their own service. Looks like they're using https://github.com/sleeping-owl/admin.